# Meaning of abbreviation "docker_gwbridge" or what does "GW" actually mean?

Tags: docker, networking

I'm new to networking and I'm trying to figure out the different abbreviation in order to get a better understanding and obviously I'm involved in docker currently. I was wondering what does "GW" in "docker_gwbridge" actually mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19298) and because it's defined in the file [default_gateway_linux.go](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/master/default_gateway_linux.go#L10), it appears that `gw` means gateway. "Gateway" is also mentioned several times in the [docs for docker_gwbridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#customize-the-docker_gwbridge-interface). A **network gateway** is provides interoperability between two networks and contains devices to translate between each end of the network. In Docker's case, this is used to allow multiple Docker daemons [to interact in a swarm](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) by linking their network layer to allow containers running on different hosts to communicate over the network.

#### Use Case

From the docs: The `docker_gwbridge` is a virtual bridge that connects the overlay networks (including the ingress network) to an individual Docker daemon’s physical network.

The reason this virtual bridge exists is to be an entrypoint to connect Docker daemons to the networking layer of an individual Docker daemon host. Again from the docs, an `ingress` and a `docker_gwbridge` are created when starting Docker by default. A possible use case for a `docker_gwbridge` is to manually specify the subnet of an existing bridge network from another Docker daemon.

#### Example

From the docs, this is how that would work:

1. Stop Docker.
2. Delete the existing docker_gwbridge interface.

```
$ sudo ip link set docker_gwbridge down
$ sudo ip link del dev docker_gwbridge
```

3. Start Docker. Do not join or initialize the swarm.
4. Create or re-create the docker_gwbridge bridge manually with your custom settings, using the docker network create command. This example uses the subnet `10.11.0.0/16`. For a full list of customizable options, see Bridge driver options.

```
$ docker network create \
    --subnet 10.11.0.0/16 \
    --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=docker_gwbridge \
    --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc=false \
    --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=true \
    docker_gwbridge
```

5. Initialize or join the swarm. Since the bridge already exists, Docker does not create it with automatic settings.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification!  It was indeed used multiple times but I don`t think they mentioned what it means exactly.In the beginning when you usually start using some acronym you specify what it means in most cases.

Comment: @AndreyanEnchevBoyadzhiev Did you need more clarity on what gateway means in this situation? Sorry if I'm not understanding your request. I did my best to add more clarity about what a network gateway means in this situation but please let me know if I can be more clear to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your concerns. Your answer was more than sufficient. The rest is networking basic concepts which I`m still reading and I`ll find them  out by myself. Just can`t always understand the abbreviations used, that`s all.

Comment: What does `dev` mean in `sudo ip link del dev docker_gwbridge`?

Comment: @PedroA I believe `dev` is for device since the command is deleting a virtual network device  `docker_gwbridge` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-link.8.html and you can search for `ip link delete`)